# How do I keep the current tab active?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap theme bs-admin-bcore and I want to make menu in file "menu.php" to be more dynamic.

For example, I have this code :

```
<ul id="menu" class="collapse">
    <li class="panel">
        <a href="index.php" >
            <i class="icon-table"></i> Dashboard
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="panel ">
        <a href="#" data-parent="#menu" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle" data-target="#component-nav">
            <i class="icon-tasks"> </i> UI Elements<span class="pull-right"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></span>&nbsp; <span class="label label-default">10</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="collapse" id="component-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="button.php"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i> Buttons </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

when I call `index.php` `<li class="panel">` becomes `<li class="panel active">` and when I call `button.php` EU Elements becomes active.

Comment: Can you elaborate the question? Do you want to add the active class to the li that contains the href of the currentpage?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "active" class to the parent li of buttons as well n it will work.